# Root htaccess overriding the sub folder htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htaccess file in root and another htaccess in films folder. I want to stop all the rewrite urls or conditions to affect the films folder. I have some other rules in film folder htaccess.

My root htaccess looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.in/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

My sub directory films folder htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /films/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^change-password/$ changepassword.php
RewriteRule ^change-password$ changepassword.php
```

The above code is just a glimpse of my original htaccess

Comment: What happens when you go to the /films folder? does it redirect you back to the root?

Comment: Yes, it redirects me to the root folder  @starkeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by following code :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/films/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It may help you.

Comment: can you please try this solution?

Comment: Yes, it works and my forms are also working. Thanks ... It works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

In `/films/.htaccess` ,Change your rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/films/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect all /films requests to www, you can use something like the following :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: the page got redirected to the films folder but now my forms in the films folder are not working.. I am calling them using ajax and i want www in the url.